# OpenCV invalid operands error

Tags: c++, ios, opencv

I'm trying to compile some OpenCV code without success. So please if you can help me It would be really nice.

This is the code:

```
cv::Vec3b c = my_cv_mat.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j) / interval;
cv::Vec3b t = another_cv_mat.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j) / interval;
```

The error is:

```
Invalid operands to binary expression ('cv::Vec<unsigned char,3>' and 'int')
```

One thing to note is that I am compiling an iOS app with OpenCV support.Any ideas how can I fix this?. I already checked the source code and it's exactly the same as other projects which are working fine.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: That code compiles fine for me. You might need to provide more details in order to get a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your `my_cv_mat` and your `another_cv_mat` an image with three channels? If it is not your code will probably result in an error or return bogus values. You are probably using a grayscale or binary image. In that case use `cv::uchar` in stead of `cv::Vec3b`.

Comment: Be careful--If those `cv::Mat`s do not have three channels, the code **will** compile. The results will be meaningless, though.